# Design array with arrows with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

I would like to draw something like this with Tikz:

[image]

I started with this but it didn't work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1) {$a$};
\node (2) {$b$};
\node (3) {$c$};
\node (4) {$d$};
\node (5) {$e$};
\node (6) {$f$};
\node (7) {$g$};
\node (8) {$h$};
\node (9) {$i$};
\node (10) {$j$};
\node (11) {$k$};
\node (12) {$l$};
\node (13) {$m$};
\node (14) {$n$};
\node (15) {$o$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Every symbol gets added to the same place.

I'd prefer to avoid giving any arguments to `tikzpicture` because after diving into the documentation I didn't understand what I could or couldn't add as argument.

Comment: Every symbol gets added to the same place because TikZ chooses the origin by default if you don't specify a position explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Right, that's what the deleted screenshot was showing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your nodes form chain of nodes, so I would use `chains` library for placement of nodes.
- For nodes I would define style, which write labels above them.
- For nodes and labels content I would employ `\foreach`loop:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, 
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=10mm, outer sep=0pt,
                 label = {[label distance=8mm, font=\small, text=blue]above:#1},
                 on chain}
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {16, 14, 10, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 1}
    \node [N=\j] (n\j) {\i};
% 
\draw   (n1.north) to [bend left] (n2.north) 
        (n1.north) to [bend left] (n3.north)
        (n3.north) to [bend left] (n6.north)
        (n3.north) to [bend left] (n7.north)
        (n5.north) to [bend left] (n10.north)
%
        (n1.south) to [bend right] (n3.south)
        (n3.south) to [bend right] (n6.south)
        (n3.south) to [bend right] (n7.south)
        (n5.south) to [bend right] (n10.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP has lines that are vertical or almost vertical  at the point they join the horizontal array of numbers. That seems to be the main difference.

Comment: @Simd,  on the sketch, yes. But apparently (s)he liked style as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and TikZ to draw the arrows). The environment `{NiceTabular}`  is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and arrows. It's possible to use TikZ and those nodes to draw whatever arrow you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=6pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}[columns-width=auto]{*{10}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\[5mm]
\Block[hvlines,fill=gray!50]{1-*}{}
16 & 14 & 10 & 8 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (2-|1.5) to [out = 90, in = 90, distance =  0.8em] (2-|2.5)  
              (2-|1.5) to [out = 90, in = 90, distance =  1.6em] (2-|3.5) 
              (2-|3.5) to [out = 90, in = 90, distance =  0.8em] (2-|6.5)  
              (2-|3.5) to [out = 90, in = 90, distance =  1.6em] (2-|7.5)  
              (2-|5.5) to [out = 90, in = 90, distance =  0.8em] (2-|10.5)  
              (3-|2.5) to [out = -90, in = -90, distance =  0.8em] (3-|4.5) 
              (3-|2.5) to [out = -90, in = -90, distance =  1.6em] (3-|5.5) 
              (3-|4.5) to [out = -90, in = -90, distance =  0.8em] (3-|8.5) 
              (3-|4.5) to [out = -90, in = -90, distance =  1.6em] (3-|9.5) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: The OP has lines that are vertical or almost vertical at the point they join the horizontal array of numbers. That seems to be the main difference.

Comment: @Simd: You are right. I have modified my answer.

Comment: You should use `*{10}{c}` instead of `cccccccccc` because it is easier to understand.

Comment: @projetmbc: You are right. I have modified my answer.

Comment: You can also use `\pgfmathwidth{"88"}` followed by `\begin{NiceTabular}[columns-width=\pgfmathresult pt]{*{10}{c}}` to prepare the coding for a dedicated macro.

Comment: @projetmbc: Good suggestion. I have modified my code with `columns-width=auto`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you're going to have to learn something sometime.

Here's a small macro that uses the [`graphs` library's syntax](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs).

```
\tikzsymbolrow[<options>]{<label distance>}{<widest node>}{<list>}{<connections>}
```

- The `<options>` get added to the options to the TikZ picture if you need them.
- The `<label distance>` specifies the distance of the labels 1, 2, … to the boxes.
- The `<widest node>` is used to determine the width of all boxes.
- The `<list>` contains the numbers for the boxes.
- The `<connection>` uses the `graphs` library's syntax to connect the boxes.

  - Use `join ^` to have them join above them and
  - use `join v` to have them join below.

  The optional value (default 1) allows you do choose another distance for the connection.

There are certainly other ways to specify the connections but I like the syntax of the `graphs` library.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\tikzset{
  join ^/.style={out= 90, in= 90, distance=(#1)*.5em}, join ^/.default=1,
  join v/.style={out=-90, in=-90, distance=(#1)*.5em}, join v/.default=1}
\newcommand*\tikzsymbolrow[5][]{%
  \tikz[every label/.append style={node font=\small},label distance={#2},#1]
    \graph[
      branch right sep=+0pt,
      nodes={
        shape=rectangle,
        text width=width("{#3}"),
        align=center,
        text height=+.7em,
        text depth=+0pt,
        draw,
        outer sep=+0pt,
        fill=gray!50,
      },
    ]{
      \foreach[count=\i] \v in {#4}{
        \v[label=\i]
      },
      #5%
    };%
}
\begin{document}
\tikzsymbolrow{1em}{00}{16, 14, 10, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 1}{
    16 --[join ^]     14 --[join v] 8 --[join v] 2,
    16 --[join ^ = 2] 10 --[join ^] 9,
     3 --[join ^ = 2] 10,
    14 --[join v = 2]  7 --[join ^] 1,
     4 --[join v = 2]  8
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Great output and great API.

Comment: @projetmbc If OP doesn't want to learn (valid opinion – PG/TikZ can be scary – even if it mightn't be welcome here) I think it would be better to have a generalization of the problem stated and a nicer input syntax (i.e. a macro) which tries to replicate their image. Sure, the first two mandatory arguments could be keys as well as but it doesn't seem like a good idea given OP's remarks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it, as a kind of starter.

You did read and tried the tutorials in part I of the pgfmanual, did you? You know the ingredients of an MWE, do you?

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        gr/.style={draw,fill=gray!20,minimum width=1.5em}
    ]
    \matrix[row sep=5mm]{
        \node {1}; & \node {2}; & \node {3}; &\node {4}; \\
        \node[gr] (16) {16}; &\node[gr] (14) {14}; & 
        \node[gr] (10) {10}; &\node[gr] (8) {8}; \\
    };
    \draw (14.south) to [out=290,in=250] (8.south);
    \draw (10.north) to [out=90,in=90] (16.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### P.S.: A short guide through syntax and tutorials of part I

There are a [pdf version](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and a [web version](https://tikz.dev/) of the pgfmanual available. Some hints for the confused.

A basic concept are **nodes**. Most of the time you have at least to tell tikz, where to place it, like `\node at (3,2) {};` (with empty text, which would be here `{any text}`). If you want retrive its position later, e.g. for drawing lines, you may want to remember where it was. Place a placeholder, like `A`, like so: `\node (A) at (3,2) {};` . You reference it later by putting `(A)`, which simplified means: look up `(  )` where you put `A` and use that coordinate.

Another basic concept is **drawing lines**, like `\draw (3,2) -- (3,-1);` or, if you placed a second node before as shortcut: `\draw (A) -- (B);`.

draw-ing is described in ch 2.3, 2.4 and elsewhere. Look for nodes at the end of ch. 3.4 and of course in ch. 3.3 .

**Options** you'll need most of the time are for drawing outer shapes of a node and specifying color if its fill. Magically `[draw,fill=yellow]` will draw a node with black outer and yellow inner, `\node[draw,fill=yellow] at (-1,-2) {};`.

Because putting such statements to each and every node, not regarding changes, is very cumbersome, there's a shortcut, named `style`. Scan the many example codes for "**style**", and see ch. 2.8, ch. 3.5 or ch. 5.1 .

The tikz-**matrix** is the analogy to Latex' tables, and introduced in ch. 5.3 . ... that's why nodes come without an explicite coordinate ...

When drawing you can replace the standard **connection** `--` by e.g. `to [out=90,in=90]`, which let you specify the leaving and entering angles of a line. See ch. 3.10 about in the middle.

**Anchors** (north, south, west, east etc.) are first introduced in ch. 2.21 .

Almost always, when you search for details of these commands in the huge remaining parts of the **pgfmanual**, you'll find enough info, at least by example, to answer questions you may have.

Having written this, non of my tikz-realted statement should remain a surprise ... if the **tutorial** was read, perhaps reread again, and tried.

Comment: I don't understand your code. You edited my post to add a sample but your example in the comment doesn't look maintainable. The last part of my question asks for no custom styles so that I wouldn't struggle to maintain it. I had a look at the tutorial but focused on the documentation because of the "unofficial" mention in the title.

Comment: @Dunno You have a good starting code. If you need an automatic method for typing your annotated table structure, you'll need to create a dedicated macro.

Comment: @Dunno, I added the visual result of your code. A screenshot is always useful, so please show what your code produces. // Just delete the ˋ[ ]ˋ and check the outcome. // Please take some time to study and try the tutorials. If you did, unfortunately you weren‘t successful enough. All I used, is also in part I, the tutorials.

Comment: @Dunno, kindly check and contemplate my P.S. add-on to my answer.